# How to fetch input from text box and print in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React trying to write a very simple project that fetches input of both text boxes and when button is clicked, the 'data' in text boxes is printed on paragraph.

How do I fetch text's in input text boxes when button is clicked?

```
class Input extends Component {
    state = { 
        tagged: false,
        message: '', 
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({tagged: true});
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('The link was clicked.');
    }

    render() {                                                
        return (
            <div id="id" style={divStyle}>
                <p> hello </p>
                <input
                    style = {textStyle}
                    placeholder="user@email.com" 
                    type="text">
                </input>

                <input
                    style = {textStyle}
                    placeholder="tag" 
                    type="text">
                </input>
                <button
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                    style={buttonStyle}>
                    {this.state.tagged ? 'Tagged' : 'Tag ' } 
                </button>

                <p>
                    {this.state.tagged ? 'Clicked' : 'Still' }
                </p>
            </div>    
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add onChange event handler in each input.

```
class Input extends Component {
    state = { 
        tagged: false,
        message: '',
        input1: '',
        input2: '',
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        // access input values in the state
        console.log(this.state) // {tagged: true, input1: 'text', input2: 'text2'}
        this.setState({tagged: true});
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('The link was clicked.');
    }

    handleInputChange = (e, name) => {
      this.setState({
       [name]: e.target.value
     })
    }

    render() {                                                
        return (
            <div id="id" style={divStyle}>
                <p> hello </p>
                <input
                    style = {textStyle}
                    placeholder="user@email.com" 
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, 'input1')}
                >
                </input>

                <input
                    style = {textStyle}
                    placeholder="tag" 
                    type="text"
                   onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, 'input2')}
               >
                </input>
                <button
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                    style={buttonStyle}>
                    {this.state.tagged ? 'Tagged' : 'Tag ' } 
                </button>

                <p>
                    {this.state.tagged ? 'Clicked' : 'Still' }
                </p>
            </div>    
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways of working with `react` inputs - you can either make them `controlled` or `uncontrolled`. When you say `fetch` text from `input`s, this is called uncontrolled components and means that form data is handled by the DOM itself and not by react.

This is achieved by using `ref` and literally getting a reference to your input and fetching its value when you need it. you can read more about this approach in [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), it is recommended using  `controlled` components

> In most cases, we recommend using controlled
>   components to implement forms. In a controlled 
>   component, form data is handled by a React component.

This means that you don’t use references to the inputs and instead handle changes of your inputs with an event handler and update `state` with the new values that the user has entered into the input fields. According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) here is how `react` handles `form` with controlled components:

> the React component that
>   renders a form also controls what happens in that form on subsequent
>   user input. An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a “controlled component”.

In your case you can do this if you choose controlled inputs:

```
class ControlledInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tagged: false,
      firstInput: '',
      secondInput: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ tagged: true });
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

  render() {
    const { firstInput, secondInput, tagged } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id="id">
        {tagged && <p>{firstInput} {secondInput}</p> }
        <input 
          value={firstInput} 
          name="firstInput"
          onChange={this.handleChange} 
          type="text" />
        <input 
          value={secondInput} 
          name="secondInput"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          type="text" />
        <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
          {tagged ? 'Tagged' : 'Tag '}
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here you put the inputs' values on `state` and update `state` when the user writes something in your inputs. If you however want to use uncontrolled components you can do it this way:

```
class UncontrolledInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tagged: false,
    message: '',
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const messageFromInputs = `${this.firstInput.value} ${this.secondInput.value}`;
    this.setState({ tagged: true, message: messageFromInputs });   
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="id">
        <p>{this.state.message}</p>
        <input ref={(input) => this.firstInput = input} type="text" />
        <input ref={(input) => this.secondInput = input} type="text" />
        <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
          {this.state.tagged ? 'Tagged' : 'Tag '}
        </button>
        <p>
          {this.state.tagged ? 'Clicked' : 'Still'}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }    
}
```

Here you will actually `fetch` values from your inputs when the button is clicked.

I made a working example with both ways on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v8ro6y9v65).